# With ListView, can I create tables to enter grades and display calculation results?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm a novice in Xamarin Apps. I want to create an app (android platform) that calculates various grades. For that, I need to create a table which receives data from various fields.

Example:

Target Grade: 95

- Grade1: Score got=50, Score=50, Assigment/Exam Weight=25%
- Grade2: Score got=75, Score=80, Assigment/Exam Weight=25%
- Grade3: Score got=35, Score=40, Assigment/Exam Weight=25%
- Grade4: Score got=" ", Score=100, Assigment/Exam Weight=25%

After receiving the data, another table will be created to display the average grade and additional grade needed to achieve a target grade

Example:

- Average Grade: 93.8
- Additional Needed: 99

From what I've read in Microsofts Docs "Xamarin.Forms ListView" seems best for data entries that require scrolling or adding a new data entry row but it seems to be more for listing things rather than adding data to calculate.

With ListView, can I create tables to enter the data and display calculation results? If not, what do you recommend?

Comment: yes, you can use a ListView with an Editor control in each cell, but this is probably better suited to a DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When you say DataGrid do you mean the one from Syncfusion or Xamarin.Forms Grid?

Comment: it's a bit of a generic term - there are a couple of commercial options, as well as some open source ones

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check it out!

Comment: You can also use a collectionview with a grid layout
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout